# Check which area user is using Google Maps and calculating delivery cost for the same

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to a create **delivery** system `(Android App)` for my `restaurant` but am stuck in the part where I calculate the delivery cost. We have only 2 charges one is for `within 8kms` and other is for `above 8kms`. When a user provides an address I need to know the distance of the address from the `restaurant` to calculate the delivery charge.

Which **Google maps API** function should I use?
And how to do it?

Comment: There's a Google Maps Directions API which you could then use to calculate distance from start to end using SphericalUtil google maps utility.

Comment: [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) is suitable as well.